# Use inverse LIKE in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, concatenation, sql-like

Hey guys this is my first question here Basically I would like to achieve this select in LARAVEL Eloquent `` SELECT * FROM `precio_canales`   WHERE JHON SMITH PORKI' LIKE CONCAT('%',precio_canales.nombre_cliente,'%') ``  So for example if I receive "JHON SMITH PORKI"  as input I expect that the database returns all querys with the name "JHON SMITH"

I have tried:

`` $precio_canal = DB::table('precio_canales')->where('Jhon Smith porki', 'LIKE', DB::raw(`CONCAT("%",precio_canales.nombre_cliente,"%"`))->get(); ``
and also:

`$precio_canal = PrecioCanales::where('Jhon smith Porki ' , 'LIKE' , DB::raw('concat("%",nombre_cliente,"%")'))->get();`

Both querys return a 500 internnal server error Any help would be much appreciated! thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where` expects a column. You need to pass a raw expression in your query.

Try either

```php
$precio_canal = DB::table('precio_canales')
    ->whereRaw('"Jhon Smith porki" LIKE CONCAT("%", precio_canales.nombre_cliente, "%")')
    ->get();
```

or

```php
$precio_canal = DB::table('precio_canales')
    ->whereRaw('"Jhon Smith porki" LIKE "%" || precio_canales.nombre_cliente || "%"')
    ->get();
```

---

You should also escape the user's input. You can do that by replacing it with a `?` and then passing the value in an array as the second parameter

```php
$precio_canal = DB::table('precio_canales')
    ->whereRaw('"?" LIKE CONCAT("%", precio_canales.nombre_cliente, "%")', ['Jhon Smith porki'])
    ->get();
```

or

```php
$precio_canal = DB::table('precio_canales')
    ->whereRaw('"?" LIKE "%" || precio_canales.nombre_cliente || "%"', ['Jhon Smith porki'])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [laravel eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)

In `where` method, **first** parameter is column name, **second** is comparasion operator (optional) and **thir** is comparator value.

So your query should be:

```
$precio_canal = DB::table('precio_canales')
->where(DB::raw(`precio_canales.nombre_cliente`), 'LIKE', '%Jhon Smith porki%')
->get();
```